# Substrate node template tutorial connected to polkadotjs app showing 0 account balances

Tags: rust, substrate

I am new to this
I am following the Substrate node and new to. t template tutorial and connected to the Polkadot js app.
When I navigate to the Accounts section 0 balances are shown for all the accounts. How to define balances for Accounts?

Polkadoitjs app Account section
[image]

Substrate front end template errord
[image]

chain_spec :-

```
use node_template_runtime::{
    AccountId, AuraConfig, BalancesConfig, GenesisConfig, GrandpaConfig, Signature, SudoConfig,
    SystemConfig, WASM_BINARY,
};
use sc_service::ChainType;
use sp_consensus_aura::sr25519::AuthorityId as AuraId;
use sp_core::{sr25519, Pair, Public};
use sp_finality_grandpa::AuthorityId as GrandpaId;
use sp_runtime::traits::{IdentifyAccount, Verify};

// The URL for the telemetry server.
// const STAGING_TELEMETRY_URL: &str = "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/";

/// Specialized `ChainSpec`. This is a specialization of the general Substrate ChainSpec type.
pub type ChainSpec = sc_service::GenericChainSpec<GenesisConfig>;

/// Generate a crypto pair from seed.
pub fn get_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> <TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public {
    TPublic::Pair::from_string(&format!("//{}", seed), None)
        .expect("static values are valid; qed")
        .public()
}

type AccountPublic = <Signature as Verify>::Signer;

/// Generate an account ID from seed.
pub fn get_account_id_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> AccountId
where
    AccountPublic: From<<TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public>,
{
    AccountPublic::from(get_from_seed::<TPublic>(seed)).into_account()
}

/// Generate an Aura authority key.
pub fn authority_keys_from_seed(s: &str) -> (AuraId, GrandpaId) {
    (get_from_seed::<AuraId>(s), get_from_seed::<GrandpaId>(s))
}

pub fn development_config() -> Result<ChainSpec, String> {
    let wasm_binary =
        WASM_BINARY.ok_or_else(|| "Development wasm binary not available".to_string())?;

    Ok(ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        // Name
        "Development",
        // ID
        "dev",
        ChainType::Development,
        move || {
            testnet_genesis(
                wasm_binary,
                // Initial PoA authorities
                vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Alice")],
                // Sudo account
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                // Pre-funded accounts
                vec![
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
                ],
                true,
            )
        },
        // Bootnodes
        vec![],
        // Telemetry
        None,
        // Protocol ID
        None,
        // Properties
        None,
        // Extensions
        None,
    ))
}

pub fn local_testnet_config() -> Result<ChainSpec, String> {
    let wasm_binary =
        WASM_BINARY.ok_or_else(|| "Development wasm binary not available".to_string())?;

    Ok(ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        // Name
        "Local Testnet",
        // ID
        "local_testnet",
        ChainType::Local,
        move || {
            testnet_genesis(
                wasm_binary,
                // Initial PoA authorities
                vec![
                    authority_keys_from_seed("Alice"),
                    authority_keys_from_seed("Bob"),
                ],
                // Sudo account
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                // Pre-funded accounts
                vec![
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie//stash"),
                ],
                true,
            )
        },
        // Bootnodes
        vec![],
        // Telemetry
        None,
        // Protocol ID
        None,
        // Properties
        None,
        // Extensions
        None,
    ))
}

/// Configure initial storage state for FRAME modules.
fn testnet_genesis(
    wasm_binary: &[u8],
    initial_authorities: Vec<(AuraId, GrandpaId)>,
    root_key: AccountId,
    endowed_accounts: Vec<AccountId>,
    _enable_println: bool,
) -> GenesisConfig {
    GenesisConfig {
        frame_system: Some(SystemConfig {
            // Add Wasm runtime to storage.
            code: wasm_binary.to_vec(),
            changes_trie_config: Default::default(),
        }),
        pallet_balances: Some(BalancesConfig {
            // Configure endowed accounts with initial balance of 1 << 60.
            balances: endowed_accounts
                .iter()
                .cloned()
                .map(|k| (k, 1 << 60))
                .collect(),
        }),
        pallet_aura: Some(AuraConfig {
            authorities: initial_authorities.iter().map(|x| (x.0.clone())).collect(),
        }),
        pallet_grandpa: Some(GrandpaConfig {
            authorities: initial_authorities
                .iter()
                .map(|x| (x.1.clone(), 1))
                .collect(),
        }),
        pallet_sudo: Some(SudoConfig {
            // Assign network admin rights.
            key: root_key,
        }),
    }
}
```

Run command :-

```
./target/release/node-template \
  --base-path /tmp/alice \
  --chain local \
  --alice \
  --port 30333 \
  --ws-port 9944 \
  --rpc-port 9933 \
  --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
  --telemetry-url 'wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0' \
  --validator
```

Tutorial URL:- https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/

apps versions shown in polkadotjs/apps

```
Substrate Node v3.0.0
api v4.14.1
apps v0.93.2-11
```

Errors in the browser console

```
logger.js:61 2021-06-17 08:24:07             DRR: Unable to decode storage system.account: entry 0:: createType(AccountInfo):: {"nonce":"Index","consumers":"RefCount","providers":"RefCount","sufficients":"RefCount","data":"AccountData"}:: Decoded input doesn't match input, received 0x0000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (76 bytes), created 0x0000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000…0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (80 bytes)
```

Comment: @co2fe Which node template tutorial exactly are you following?

Comment: did you run with the `--dev` flag?

Comment: @JimmyChu Updated

Comment: @NukeManDan Updated with the command

Comment: using what version of the node? v3? or possibly https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/v3.0.0+monthly-2021-05 --- give that version a try, if you are willing. Also look at your browser console logs -- there may be errors.

Comment: @NukeManDan yep v3

Comment: @NukeManDan yes there are errors, updated the question with errors and the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clear all node cache and rust cache
Install node dependencies and substrate dependencies
Then it's working

Please note

- Install latest libraries as mentioned in the tutorial after clearing cache in local dev environment